# injecting properties to different instances of same class (Spring Framework)

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

"Do mark it duplicate if required but please leave a solution link in the comments."
I have a class "Assignment22.Player.java" of which I have to create 5 instances and inject properties to them. I can inject properties to the instances by hard coding them in the XML file itself. But I want to do that in such a manner that I do not have to go to the XML file to change the properties in case there is some "change" requirement in the future. That can be achieved using one/more properties file. 
Here is what I tried to do: 
I created five properties file for five different instances. But, since, the class is same hence the properties' names for every object will be same. So seemingly, I can't use the properties files this way. 
here is the xml code that I tried:

```
  <!-- country bean  -->
  <bean id = "country1" class="Assignmetn22.Country">
    <property name= "countryId" value="${countryId}"></property>
    <property name= "countryName" value="${countryName}"></property>
  </bean>
  <bean id = "country2" class="Assignmetn22.Country">
   <!-- since the properties' names are same there won't any effect if assign them different values 
  and use them for different beans.
   -->
 </bean>


 <bean id = "player1" class="Assignment22.Player">
   <property name="playerId"  value="${playerId}"></property>
   <property name="playerName" value="${playrName}"></property>
   <property name="country" ref="country1"></property>
 </bean>

 <bean id = "player2" class="Assignment22.Player">
   <!-- same properties' names for other bean -->
   <!-- since the properties' names are same there won't any effect if assign them different values 
  and use them for different beans.
   -->
   <!--   <property name="playerId"  value="${playerId}"></property>
          <property name="playerName" value="${playrName}"></property>
          <property name="country" ref="country2"></property>
    -->
  </bean>


  <!--loading the properties file-->
    <bean id= "placeholderConfig1" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
     <property name="location"  value="classpath:p1.properties"></property>
   </bean>
   <bean id= "placeholderConfig2" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location"  value="classpath:p2.properties"></property>
  </bean>
   <bean id= "placeholderConfig3" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location"  value="classpath:p3.properties"></property>
   </bean>
  <bean id= "placeholderConfig4" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location"  value="classpath:p4.properties"></property>
 </bean>
 <bean id= "placeholderConfig5" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
   <property name="location"  value="classpath:p5.properties"></property>
  </bean>
```

I need to know how can I inject different properties values to different beans of same reference type (that have same properties' names) dynamically. I do not want to hard code them using XML. Is there any java way? please explain.

Answer (score 2):

You may use Spring@Value annotations inside your beans. Spring will fill your property value in for you when a new instance of is created.

```
public class Player
{
     @Value("${playerName}")
     private String playerName;
}
```

If you want to stick with XML-configuration and not use annotations, create a bean that holds your properties and wire it into your Player-Beans.

Use scope="prototype" on the playerProperties to have one instance created for every player. This way players won't share those Properties.

Use scope="singleton" (this is the default) to have Player instances share the PlayerProperties Bean.

```
public class Player
{
    PlayerProperties props;
}

public class PlayerProperties
{
    String playerName;
    //getter,setter,...
}


<bean id = "player2" class="Player">
   <property name="props"  ref="playerProperties"></property>
   ...
</bean>


<bean id = "playerProperties" class="PlayerProperties" scope="prototype">
    <property name="playerName" value="${playrName}"></property>
    ...
</bean>
```

Comment: In a given property file, there will unique **property = value** pairs. And for a given class' five objects will have the same property names(instance variables). For Example-  'ClassObj obj1, obj2; obj1.name="TomB"; obj2.name="zerobyzero" ' .  The problem is how do I inject values to **name** attribute of obj1 and obj2 separately? I do not want to hard code that using XML. Suggest me some java way or using properties file.

Answer (score 0):

Application class:

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableConfigurationProperties 
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication

//use players.properties
@PropertySource("classpath:players.properties") 
public class InstancePropsApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(InstancePropsApp.class, args);
    }

    //Create 3 Player Beans (could be done in XML-Config, too)
    @Bean Player player1() {return new Player();}
    @Bean Player player2() {return new Player();}
    @Bean Player player3() {return new Player();}

    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {
        //Output values after init. 
        player1().echoName();
        player2().echoName();
        player3().echoName();
    }

}
```

Player class

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
//Make bean aware of it's name to use bean name as property prefix
public class Player implements BeanNameAware  {

    @Autowired
    private ConfigurableEnvironment environment;

    private String name;


    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    private String beanName;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        //init this beans properties from "beanName.xxx" values. e.g. 
        //player1.name and player2.name ans so on
        new RelaxedDataBinder(this, beanName).bind(new 
        PropertySourcesPropertyValues(environment.getPropertySources()));
    }

    //We use our very own bean name as prefix to load properties per
    //prototype instance
    public void setBeanName(String beanName) {
        this.beanName = beanName;
    }

    public void echoName()
    {
        System.out.println(beanName + " : " + name);
    }

}
```

players.properties:

```
player1.name=max
player2.name=theo
player3.name=karren
```

Will print

```
player1 : max
player2 : theo
player3 : karren
```